# The idea behind Cuberto website hover and paralex animations

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, css-animations

Can any one explain what is the idea behind Cuberto animations in their home page?:
https://cuberto.com/

I have grabbed the concept of the mouse hover effects on texts, and how the videos are shown, but still found difficulties on grabbing the idea of the paralex effects when scrolling over the projects and their images.

How the image transitions effects are done that way? How can we achieve the morphing effects of those image transitions and their animations?

And when we hover the image of the project, their is a beautiful and smooth effect happened on that image, what do we call that effect? And how can we achieve it?

Note that I am open to use any library, so feel free to suggest any library you think it may help creating such animations.

Comment: You might be interested in the [GreenSock Animation Platform](https://greensock.com/gsap/).

Comment: @showdev I am, and I have used it many times in my projects, but my problem is how to  achieve the effects of Cuberto using gsap  or any other library if it helps.

Comment: Cuberto appears to use GSAP. It might help to identify one effect, show what you've attempted, and let us know what specifically goes wrong.

Comment: @showdev I know they use gsap, and I have tried to achieve their curser hover effects with gsap,and it worked very well, but I am still stuck on how to achieve the other effects of the projects images. Like when you hover on image, there is some kind of stretching and skewing, what are those effects exactly, and how to achieve them?

Comment: For that effect they are most likely using WebGL, Codrops has a similar effect in one of their articles https://tympanus.net/codrops/2019/09/04/a-configurator-for-creating-custom-webgl-distortion-effects/

Comment: Are you referring to the [squash and stretch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squash_and_stretch) on circles when you move the mouse? It looks like they might be distorting the element with [`transform:scale(x,y)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform), calculating values based on mouse pointer velocity ("momentum-based animations"), possibly using [`ThrowPropsPlugin`](https://greensock.com/docs/v2/Plugins/ThrowPropsPlugin).

Comment: For inspiration, check out [this excerpt](https://jsfiddle.net/opf8y2eL/) from the site's [JavaScript bundle](https://cuberto.com/assets/js/bundle.js). It seems to be a "move" event handler that calculates X and Y scaling based on mouse velocity.

Comment: @showdev Thanks for the references you mentioned, and I think what JHeth mentioned is somehow close to part of what I was looking for, I will give a try!  Thank you very much!

Comment: Still need to know the image transition effect when scrolling though? Do you have any Idea, the animated waves when image  appears, is it clip path? or something else!

Comment: The [MorphSVGPlugin](https://greensock.com/morphsvg/) might be helpful to animate SVG paths, something like [this](https://greensock.com/forums/topic/16172-svg-wave-animation/page/2/).